# Does a Canadian permanent resident need a transit visa in Canada?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas, canadian-residents

I hava an Indian passport with a valid US work visa, a valid Canadian PR card.

I am traveling to Delhi from Chicago via Toronto. My understanding is that I will require to apply for a transit visa for Canada in order to take my flight from Toronto to Chicago. My first question is that do I need to have a transit visa while I possess a Canadian PR card?

I visited Canada earlier in April to complete all PR requirements and returned to USA after a week to finish my projects. The PR card was shipped to me to USA by one of my uncles.

Comment: I’m slightly confused - are you in Delhi and your Canadian PR card is in the US?

Comment: No, I am in USA, traveling to Delhi. My PR card is with me.

Comment: Will this be your very first time entering Canada as a PR? Because that is a special case. (Though you still don't need a transit visa).

Comment: It will be my first visit after getting PR. I visited there earlier this year to finish formalities after I received COPR.

Comment: OK, then you will be fine.

Answer (score 11):

Citizens and permanent residents of Canada don't need a visa to enter Canada. Now that you are a permanent resident, you have a guaranteed [right to enter Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/pr-card/understand-pr-status.html) without a visa (as well as live and work in Canada). The PR card serves as evidence of this right. Show it in addition to your passport when you check in for your flight.

Comment: Thanks, Michael! It’s good information. My first flight to Toronto is with Air Canada and then there is a connection with United Airlines to Chicago. I still can’t understand as to why I will require to go through Canadian immigration to take my flight to Chicago. Your answer satisfies me that I will not be having issues in Toronto. As long as I have a valid PR card I should be able to transit through Toronto to Chicago.

Comment: @Curioussam You probably won't go through Canada immigration. Over the past few years Canada has been building sterile transit areas in its airports for passengers transiting to US preclearance that bypasses Canadian immigration, and Pearson has such an area already. But Canada's transit airside without visa program is also relatively new and only open to a few nationalities so far. Of course as a permanent resident none of this applies to you, but it may apply to people you know who aren't permanent residents.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks again, Michael! I am sure that I don’t need to be worried anymore. Thanks for your time to answer my questions!

Comment: @Curioussam I see that your question was changed and now indicates that you are traveling from the US, rather than to the US. In that case you will go through Canada immigration at Toronto to change flights, but because you are a PR you will still have no problem with it.

Comment: I might have said that as I am traveling. If I said it differently I reiterate that I am going to US from India transiting through Canada.